# package 'translations' does not have a namespace and should be re-installed

Tags: r, namespaces

I am new in R. I already installed fBasics, plyr, and dplyr, then.

```
library(fBasics)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

lapply(.packages(all.available = TRUE), function(xx) library(xx, character.only = TRUE))
```

the result was that `(Error in library(xx, character.only = TRUE) :  package 'translations' does not have a namespace and should be re-installed)`

I don't know what to do next. Please help me out?
Note: I searched for translations package, but it does not exist in CRAN

I am using desktop window office 365, 64 bits.

Comment: why are you doing the lapply() step?

Comment: If that line worked it would load ever package you have installed on your machine. That really seems overkill and prone to error. There's no need for that `lapply` line if you just want to use the three packages you've already loaded.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks for your support